# How to remove these wrinkles/stress lines

Tags: faces

I'm trying to remove these creases from the faces, what are some of the best approaches to clean this up?[image]

Comment: The best approach is proper modeling. Those subdivisions are due to non planar polygons. Having such long faces as part of the long cylinder will make this more evident. Try using a subsurf modifier.

Comment: In addition to what @susu said, you also want to minimize the usage of ngons in your mesh.

Comment: Can you provide your blend file? So we can check it out?

Comment: If you add a bunch of loop cuts horizontally (CTRL + R) this should minimize the tearing effect

Answer (score 0):

shade smooth + subsurface modifier

Comment: Won't work. Smooth shading is already on. The main problem are the ngons and the resulting non-planar and quite long triangles. Also, 4 words rarely make a good answer.